# extracting multiple instances regex python

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
This is @lame
```

Here I want to extract lame. But here is the issue, the above string can be

```
This is lame
```

Here I dont extract anything. And then this string can be:

```
This is @lame but that is @not
```

Here i extract lame and not

So, output I am expecting in each case is:

```
 [lame]
 []
 [lame,not]
```

How do I extract these in robust way in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find multiple patterns; in this case for anything that is preceded by `@`, consisting of word characters:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=@)\w+', inputtext)
```

The `(?<=..)` construct is a *positive lookbehind assertion*; it only matches if the current position is preceded by a `@` character. So the above pattern matches 1 or more word characters (the `\w` character class) *only* if those characters were preceded by an `@` symbol.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=@)\w+', 'This is @lame')
['lame']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=@)\w+', 'This is lame')
[]
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=@)\w+', 'This is @lame but that is @not')
['lame', 'not']
```

If you plan on reusing the pattern, do compile the expression first, then use the [`.findall()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) on the compiled regular expression object:

```
at_words = re.compile(r'(?<=@)\w+')

at_words.findall(inputtext)
```

This saves you a cache lookup every time you call `.findall()`.

Comment: Just curious, how is `@(\w+)` different? It produces the same result.

Comment: @Bibhas: It is a side-effect of `.findall()` special-casing capturing groups. In a pattern that has a capturing group, only the contents of that one group is returned instead of the whole matched pattern.

Comment: @Bibhas: In this case, the end result is the same because of that.

Comment: I know. Hence I made it a group. That's what is needed here, right? At first glance `(?<=@)` confused me. But `@(\w+)` looks straight forward. I was just curious if your pattern has any advantage over the simple one.

Comment: I find both to be as simple as the other; it's just a question of recognizing the syntax, isn't it? I'd have to make comparative measurements over which one is faster.

Comment: Your solution is faster than @(\w+).  I made an example where I compared @(\w+) and (?<=@)\w+.  @(\w+) parsed all three of the OP examples in 0.0011 secs while (?<=@)\w+ completed 0.0002 secs.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the output you requested:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=@)\w+')
print regex.findall('This is @lame')
print regex.findall('This is lame')
print regex.findall('This is @lame but that is @not')
```

Comment: This will include the `@` symbol in the output.

Comment: Sure, but the OP gave us explicit expected output samples for his input cases.

Comment: Updated so that the @-symbol is removed. This will compile the regex so if you're matching multiple strings, performance is higher.

Comment: It might be that '@(\w+)' looks for a group that is arbitrary long, while '(?<=@)\w+' looks for a fixed-length group and matches the rest. This is just guessing, and maybe the first one needs to copy the data to the results. On my computer, after 100k operations they ended on ~0.25s and ~0.15s.

Comment: @Enfenion Ah, okay.  I ran some tests and the results were closer when I increase the number of runs to 100k.  I'm using python 2.6.5 and I got 0.4 sec and 0.25 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You should use re lib here is an example:

```
import re
test case = "This is @lame but that is @not"
regular = re.compile("@[\w]*")
lst= regular.findall(test case)
```

Comment: This will include the `@` symbol in the output. The `[..]` square brackets are redundant, `\w` can be used on its own. This will also return a match for the `@` character without any word characters following, because you used `*` meaning 0 or more.